# Can a UILabel be placed over UIPicker component and the text of the UILabel be updated after user picks a new value in the picker?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview, ios

How are the user's touches detected if i were to use `UILabel`s that are overlayed on each picker component? I understand how to detect the user's touches on the `UIPickerView`, but I need to update the text of the `UILabel` after the user make changes a picker component value. My method is not being called after I change the values in the picker components. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do that can’t be accomplished just using a [`UIPickerView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)? In its [`UIPickerViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html), when you receive the [`-pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#jumpTo_3) message, you can call [`[pickerView reloadComponent:someComponent];`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#jumpTo_10) to change the contents of a given row based on the user’s selections.

Comment: i am using a UIPickerView. tried using a method that would check if (x.touchInside) then set a flag and change the text of the overlying UILabel, but my method does get called after i select a different value in the underlying picker.

Comment: ...i think i have defined my struct correctly. i can step through the line of code, but not able to detect a user's touch.

Comment: I will try to place my block of code in didSelectRow. Just not sure how to detect the user's response since touchinside events are not pressent for UILabels

Comment: Why do you need to detect a touch on the `UIPickerView`? Its touch code is all built in. You might consider updating your original question with screenshots to help illustrate the problem you’re having.

Comment: i am wanting the UILabel text update to occur each time the user changes a selection.

Comment: Every time the user changes the selection in the `UIPickerView`, that picker view calls the equivalent of `[self.delegate pickerView:self didSelectRow:self.selectedRow inComponenet:self.selectedComponent];`. Put your label-changing code in that method in its delegate and you’re all set.

Comment: Interesting...i had didSelectRow commented out before i received your last comment. And, i have noticed that after uncommenting it this method is still not being called. I was thinking this method should be called each time i select a value in the picker.

Comment: Did you ever set the delegate? Something like `[pickerView setDelegate:self]` in whatever class you’re using as the delegate.

Comment: appears i didn't. attempting to set at the moment. i remember didSelectRow working before. interesting...

Comment: i am receiving an error "expected specifier-qualifier-list before'[' token" after i added your suggested line of code

Comment: i was thinking that the setDelegate method was expecting a class name. not an instance of the class. Got confused.